# Java - Printing several different parts of a split string

Tags: java, while-loop, arrays

I am having an error when I am trying to print out an Array. Though I am getting an:

```
     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
              at FlipProj.main(FlipProj.java:20)
```

Error message.

My Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class FlipProj 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Innput an equation:");
        String e = s.next();

        String split[] = e.split("-");

        int count = 0;

        while (split.length > count)
        {
                count++;
                System.out.println("Splt: " + split[count]);
        }

        s.close();
    }
}
```

Is there any way to do this properly?

Comment: Why do you increment `count` before you use it? Arrays are indexed from `0` till `lenght-1`.

Comment: I am trying to make it so that when I type in 3-665-45 (Or any other number) that the 3 numbers get separated a can be put into strings. The while-loop here is checking if the length of string is larger than count. Count is just there to stop it when it reaches the max number of length.

Answer (score 1):

You are incrementing too soon, this should work:

```
while (split.length > count) {
    System.out.println("Splt: " + split[count]);
    count++;
 }
```

Remember arrays are indexed starting from 0.

Some (cleaner) alternatives to consider:

```
//using a for loop
for (int i=0; i<split.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Splt: " + split[i]);
}
```

or

```
//using an enhanced for loop (since Java 5)
for (String str: split) {
    System.out.println("Splt: " + str);
}
```

You can find more information [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).

Answer (score 0):

When you are incrementing your count variable, you are doing it before printing from your array.  You need to remember that Java arrays always start at 0 rather than 1.  Try this:

```java
while (split.length > count){
  System.out.println("Split: " + split[count]);
  count ++;
}
```

It is suggested that you use a for loop though, as they work very well for iterating through arrays.  They also use less memory than while loops.

```
for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i ++) {
  System.out.println("Split: " + split[i]);
  count ++;
}
```

Also, an ArrayOutOfBounds exception means that you were trying to access an object in your array that doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks, I knew what a ArrayOutOfBounds was, I just had no idea why it was throwing one in this case.

Comment: Just to be sure :)  Happy coding